# Unexpected behaviour of php code that creates a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks guys, thanks for help..:)

I have one more question: I have to learn php to make web apps in my college project, I am planning to buy a php tutorial set from infinite skills (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3NNgfBeSjc1n4ttD5oSm7vbjJJB-U8bW), am I going write or is there a better option available?,..

This php code successfully creates the table in database 'rbsDb' with given columns, but it fails if I comment the last entry in the list (CompanyID), no matter what other entries does my code have. Please help I really can't understand what this last line has special in it, as commenting it does not affect the syntax..

**PHP code:**

```
{
    //   SQL script to create table tPerson 
    $createPersonTable_SQL = "CREATE TABLE rbsDb.acad ( ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "ear INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "calss VARCHAR( 20 ) , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "feel VARCHAR( 50 ) , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "LastName VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL, ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "CompanyID INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL ";  
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= ")";

    if (mysql_query($createPersonTable_SQL))  { 
        echo "'Create TABLE acad' -  Successful.<br /><br />";
    } 
}
```

Source: https://www.udemy.com/php-mysql-tutorial/#/lecture/49095

Comment: You can get the actual error by using `mysql_error`. Don't forget that if you comment out the last line, you're going to have a trailing comma at the end of the preceding line that will generate a syntax error

Comment: If you are referring to the line `$createPersonTable_SQL .= "CompanyID INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL ";`, note that it does not have a trailing comma, thus commenting it out makes the SQL syntax invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `comma`

Use

```
$createPersonTable_SQL .= "LastName VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ";
```

Insted of

```
$createPersonTable_SQL .= "LastName VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL, ";
```

if you are removing or commenting `CompanyID` column from code .